# Who is this goddess in the picture

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I found this below pic in instagram. Who is this goddess? Is any mention about this goddess in Hindu Puranas?

[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Hinduism stack exchange. Are you interested in Puranas only? If not, you can change the question body for asking from any scripture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a forum for clarifying postings on social media. You should direct your questions to the author of the media posting.

Comment: It is not necessary that these paintings are accurate descriptions of some Hindu goddesses .. paintings may not depict accurately a certain deity as per their Dhyan Slokas .. So it is always better to post the links where you got these pics from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Who is this goddess?
```

**Padmavati Devi**

(**Ps**- Do not confuse her with Padmavati Devi of Tirumala & Tiruchanur, or with the Padmavati Yakshini of Jainism.)

She is one of the 700 Mahavidyas or 13 Shaktis of Durga Saptashati or the Angavidya of Navarna Chandī and thus she is the ruling deity of the 6th chapter (Dhumralochana Vadha).

```
Is any mention about this goddess in Hindu Puranas?
```

Yes, she appears in Durga Saptashati or Markandeya Purana.

Her dhyan is mentioned in the 6th chapter of Uttam Charitra, Durga Saptashati, as below-

> ॐ नागाधीश्‍वरविष्टरां फणिफणोत्तंसोरुरत्‍नावली-
> भास्वद्देहलतां दिवाकरनिभां नेत्रत्रयोद्भासिताम्।
> मालाकुम्भकपालनीरजकरां चन्द्रार्धचूडां परां
> सर्वज्ञेश्‍वरभैरवाङ्‌कनिलयां पद्मावतीं चिन्तये॥
>
> Om, I meditate Upon The Ultimate goddess Padmavathi, who reside in the body of the Lord of all wisdom, Sarjneshwarbhairava. Her body is efflugent with the brilliance of multitude of jewels, she is adorned by the hood of the king of snakes, upon whom she is reclining. Her lustre is like that of the sun and her three eyes are brilliant. In her hands she holds, a rosary, a pitcher, a skull and a lotus, & the radiant half moon is the shining crown upon her head.

There are numerous tantric references too. An exclusive kavacham is dedicated to Padmavati Devi in the Deviyamal tantra. And she appears in Rudrayamal too. Almost every Devi Sahasranaam has her name, be it of Kali, Dhumavati, Laxmi, Bala, Bhuvaneshwari, Ganga, etc.

Deviyamala tantra,

> त्रिष्टुप छन्द इतिख्यातं देवी पद्मावती स्मृता ।
> With the famous trishtup chanda, meditated upon Devi Padmavati.

Rudrayamal tantra,

> संपत्करी च साम्राज्यलक्ष्मी: **पद्मावती** शिवा।
> दुर्गा भद्राकृतिः काली कालरात्रिः सुभद्रिका।।

Sarvajneshwar Bhairava (the all-knower/the lord of all wisdom) is the consort of Padmavati Devi.

Deviyamala tantra mentions this in a shloka,

> श्रीसर्वज्ञेश्वरसहिता श्रीपद्मावतीदेवता
> Padmavati devta, along with Shree Sarvajneshwar.

Also in the above dhyan mantra, this was mentioned,

> सर्वज्ञेश्‍वरभैरवाङ्‌कनिलयां पद्मावतीं चिन्तये॥
> I meditate upon Padmavati who resides in the body of Sarvajneshwara Bhairava.

Comment: Thank you. But, Who is Sarvajneshwara Bhairava?

Comment: @BoovanaesS Idk, about Shri Sarvajneshwar Bhairav. Will try to find about him, if in any scriptures will let u knw.