# identification request: who is this female devi, sitting on the back of a crocodile.?

Tags: scripture, gods, identification-request, goddess, rivers

I saw an identification request [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/52194/3294) but this is clearly a different one.

I saw this female devi - on the picture below - and from my wisdom I can't figure out who she might be.

Is it something backed up by scripture.?

I can see what seems to be devtas on the background.

If this is bona fide, is there are scriptural references where I can read more about this.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makara is the Vahana of Mata Ganga.

The Brihad-Dharma Purana.: Chapter 37.: The Birth of Ganga.:

> **Meanwhile, Ganga appeared before Himalaya in a dream, and showed him her true form.** She had four arms and three eyes, and her complexion was white. **She was seated on a Makara,** and was adorned with many ornaments. Her beauty was incomparable, and a fascinating smile played on her lips. Her lustre was dazzling, and all the gods were kneeling down before her.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: In this answer there were two options. Khodiyar Mata uses Trishul or a trident as her weapon. Gangaji does not have any weapon. https://khodiyarmandir.com/history

Comment: But i think that's a folklore and the op is asking for scriptural reference. And the other answer have already mentioned Khodhiyar Mata.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably “Khoḍīyār Mātā”, identified as a Hindu folk goddess worshiped in Gujarat and Rajasthan states in India (according to Wiki)

According to the thesis [“The Transformation of Village Goddesses in Gujarat, India”](https://escholarship.mcgill.ca/concern/theses/r207tt548):

> The goddesses of Gujarat are characterized by a small but not insignificant crisis of identity. This may not be immediately evident, as the female divinities of Gujarati origin, almost all of which are identifiable by the title mātā or mā (“exalted mother”), look generic enough at first blush. They may even look familiar. Their lithograph prints, extensively circulated in present-day Gujarat, follow the well-known iconography of Sanskritic goddesses such as Durgā and Sarasvatī, depicting the mātās as smiling, pacific young women, each with an identifiable vehicle (vāhana). Indeed, the goddess Ambā Mātā rides a tiger, as she is in essence a Gujarati instantiation of Durgā, a pan Indian martial goddess. More distinctively, Melaḍī Mātā sits upon a goat (Figure 1), Bahucarā Mātā a rooster, Haḍkāī Mā a dog, Momāī Mā a camel, **and Khoḍīyār Mātā is accompanied by a crocodile**. Jogaṇī Mā, whose iconography follows that of the tantric goddess Chinnamastā, also possesses a unique mount, in that she stands atop the copulating figures of Kāma and Rati.

Another option is Gaṅgā Bhagavati. An image representing such a Goddess standing on a crocodile was found during [excavations at the courtyard of Vinobaji’s Ashram](https://whatisindia.com/inscriptions/vakataka/architecturesculptureandpainting5.html).

> The conjecture about the erection of a temple dedicated to Rāma by Pravarasena II at his new capital Pravarapura, which was made by me several years ago, was based only on the evidence of these panels and was not substantiated by any inscription. That evidence has now become available unexpectedly. Recently, while digging in the courtyard of Vinōbāji’s āśrama, the image of a female deity, about 6 ft. in height, was discovered. Originally it was four-armed, but now all the arms are broken. The goddess wears several beautifully carved necklaces, a vaikakṣaka, an exquisitely carved mekhalā (girdle) and anklets. Her hair is modelled in a coiled fashion which was in vogue in the Gupta-Vākāṭaka age. Her face is serene. **She is standing on a crocodile, which marks her out as the river goddess Gaṅgā. The identification is placed beyond doubt by the inscription carved to the proper right side of her legs, viz., Gaṅgā Bhagavati (i.e. Goddess Gaṅgā)**. The characters of the inscription closely resemble those of the Paṭṭan plates of Pravarasēna II and leave no doubt that the image is of the Vākāṭaka age. This find clearly shows that there was a magnificent temple of that age just where Vinōbājī’s āśrama is now situated.

The above description does not fit the standing posture, neither the four arms. Except of course if your image is hiding one arm because I can only see three?.